# AWS S3 Bucket Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want images I uploaded to S3 bucket "fat" (Created two folders under it /men/shoes) to be accessed via url on internet - For UI JSON.

I have added bucket policy and CORS but I am getting access denied. What else should I consider.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1694408177441",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1694408172843",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395811947099:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fat/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::fat"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1694409137710",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fat/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://fat.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://fat.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Principal` to `*` in your bucket policy in order to grant everyone over the internet access to you bucket objects.

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1694408172843",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",  <-- Update Principal here
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::fat/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::fat"
    ]
},
..
..
..
```

Do you really need `s3:ListBucket` action? If not, you can remove this action to adhere with the least privileges principal.

Comment: Perfect Ankush !

Comment: @AnkushJain  Please check this could you help in this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111957/drm-encryption-and-decryption-from-mp4-to-hls-using-aws-elemental-mediaconvert