# DRM Encryption and decryption from mp4 to HLS using AWS Elemental MediaConvert

Tags: encryption, aws-media-convert, vod

***I am using  **AWS Elemental MediaConvert** to convert mp4 to hls it works fine.
now i tried to implement encryption and decryption when conversion hls.
I created job like below***

[image]

***encryption done successfully.
but when I tried to play video using video.js***

[image]

json file for encryption

```
            "Encryption": {
          "EncryptionMethod": "AES128",
          "InitializationVectorInManifest": "INCLUDE",
          "StaticKeyProvider": {
            "StaticKeyValue": "00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF",
            "Url": "enc.key"
          },
          "Type": "STATIC_KEY"
        }
```

**I am getting issues ts file not loading and unable to play video**

any steps which i missed from above

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your configuration there is an issue with the 'URL' value `enc.key`

As per the tooltip: `Relates to DRM implementation. The location of the license server used for protecting content.`

[image: MediaConvert console]

You need to specify a location on the web where your `enc.key` can be accessed. In my case, this is an Amazon S3 bucket fronted by a CloudFront distribution.

[Static key encryption parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/encrypting-content.html#static-key-encryption-parameters)

Comment: thank you for reply  but in broswer i can read key with 200 ok means file read  key successfully only ts gets error